# How to prove that $7^{15} + 7^{16} + 7^{17} - 1$ is divisible by $10$?

Tags: divisibility

This was a question on my math exam. We weren't able to use calculators so proving by manually calculating the exact value would take too long. 
In the end I ignored this question to save time but I'm still curious.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts at all on this question? Did you learn any techniques during your course? 
Hint: $7^2 =49$ which equals $-1$ (mod 10)

Comment: Well, can you get the last digit of $7^{16}$ manually, to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first make some observations:

$$ 7^1 \equiv 7 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^2 \equiv -1 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^3 \equiv 3 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^5 \equiv 7 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^6 \equiv -1 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^7 \equiv 3 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^8 \equiv 1 \mod 10$$

You can conclude (or prove by induction) that

$$ 7^{4k+1} \equiv 7 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^{4k+2} \equiv -1 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^{4k+3} \equiv 3 \mod 10$$
$$ 7^{4k+4} \equiv 1 \mod 10$$

So

$$ 7^{15} + 7^{16}+ 7^{17} - 1\equiv 3 + 1 + 7 - 1 \equiv 0 \mod 10.$$

Comment: Ok, I see how could I have done that. I didn't think of this earlier for some reason. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Try modular arithmetic: 
$$7^2=49\equiv-1\mod 10,$$
so $$7^{15}+7^{16}+7^{17}-1\equiv (-1)^{7}7+(-1)^{8}+(-1)^{8}7-1\equiv -7+1+7-1\equiv0\mod 10$$
and $7^{15}+7^{16}+7^{17}-1$ is divisible by $10$.

Answer (score 0):

$$7^{15}+7^{16}+7^{17}=7^{15}(1+7+7^2)\equiv7^{15}\cdot7\pmod{50}$$

Now $7^2=49\equiv-1\pmod{50}$

$\implies7^{16}=(7^2)^8\equiv(-1)^8\pmod{50}$

Answer (score 0):

$$7^{15}+7^{16}+7^{17}-1=57\times 7^{15}-1$$

$7^2\equiv -1\pmod {10}$ so we have $7^{14}\equiv (-1)^7\equiv -1\pmod {10}$ and therefore $7^{15}\equiv -7$ and

$$57\times 7^{15}\equiv (-3)\times (-7)\equiv 21\equiv 1\pmod {10}$$

Answer (score -1):

7^15(1+7+7^2)-1
=7^15(57)-1

(10-3)^15*(3(19))-1

(10*k - 3^15) *3 *19 -1
(10*K-3^16)*19-1

19*3^16-1 must be divisible by 10 if this is true

3^0=1
3^1=3
3^2=9
3^3=27
last digit of 3^4=1
               ^5=3
9
7...
repeats
-3^16 will have last digit of 1
19*-xxxxx1*-1

(10+9)*(-xxxxx1)-1
=-10*xxxx1 + 9*xxxxx1-1
=10*K  -xxxxxxx9 -1
=10*k-xxxxxxxx0
so 10 divides